# Apache config on Suse 10

Tags: apache-2.2

We upgraded from Suse 9 to Suse 10 which upgrade apache from 2.0.x to 2.2.x. Now I cannot access the website using the hostname. I can access using defined `ServerName` in the `VirtualHost` config but when using http://servername/path I get a `403 access denied` error. Do I have to do anything extra to be able to access the site using servername?

Answer (score 1):

check your error log.. If you use the 2.0 config with 2.2 there are module names that have changed. Your error log will tell you which modules are giving you problems.

Comment: If Module names have changed that should present problems when starting up I would assume.